# Early 70s Horror story (Flies on Chapter intro pages)

Tags: story-identification, horror, ghost

In 1974/75 I read a horror novel that freaking scared the crap out of me. [I was in High School at the time] Pretty sure it was not a vampire or mummy type story, it almost certainly involved ghosts or hauntings. I can still picture the room I was in when I almost wigged out it scared me so much. (lived in that house in 1974/75)

For the last 30 years I always thought it was "The Amityville Horror" but recently I discovered that "The Amityville Horror" was published in 1977.

It could have been paperback book published before 1975. Or possibly a hardback book I checked out from the library (which would mean it was probably a few years older)

The only thing I distinctly recall about the book is each of the Chapter intro pages had houseflies in the white space above the Chapter ## line.

The images were black and white basic outline drawings of flies. They were overhead views as opposed to side view.

There were varying amounts of flies on each Chapter intro page. Some had only a couple (1-2), some had a few (3-4) Some had more (5-8) and some had lots (a dozen or more) If I recall correctly the scarier the story go the more flies were on the Chapter intro page.

Does anyone know of a Horror Novel from the early 70s that had flies on the Chapter pages?

The story freaked me out so much that I **stopped** reading any ghost/haunting type stories after that.

Comment: Most likely, I do not know the book. However, you have a bigger chance to find the book if you describe the story, instead of the graphics inside. Memory permitting, of course. Maybe other people had a different print, with different graphics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same question almost written exactly as you did and after researching, it is the Amityville Horror. Hope that helps.   [image]

Comment: Nice!  The picture is great.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the images I was remembering/talking about.

Comment: But I would swear I read it in 1974/75 (while in high school), as I have a vivid memory of the room I was in when reading it and getting so freaking terrified while reading it (sudden strange noise in house/shadow on the window) that I was seconds from running out of the room screaming.  And I was living in a different house in 1977 when the book was apparently released...  Still to this day, I do not read horror novels, and little interest in horror movies.

Comment: But this has to be the book I was thinking of, and is the last horror novel I ever read, I must be confusing the rooms when I was growing up.